# Form validation using IIFE and closure

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, closure

> ## Problem statement
>
> Write an IIFE in which we have to validate the input provided from a form using closures. The form consists of name, email, phone, address in which name, email and phone number should not be left blank. Also validate that the given email is a valid email id using JavaScript.
>
> ## Objective
>
> This assignment will help you to master the following concepts:
>
> - function
> - closures

## Solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form validation</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 40%; margin: 0 auto;">
            <h6>Fill the form</h6>
            <form action="javascript:void(0)" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label>Last Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="lastname" required ></label> <br>
                <label>First Name: <input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="firstname" required ></label> <br>
                <label>Email: <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required 
                                        onblur="(function(id){
                                            var email_id = document.getElementById(id).value;
                                            function validate(){
                                                var regpat = /^[a-zA-Z_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
                                                return regpat.test(email_id);
                                            }
                                            alert(validate());
                                        })('email');">
                </label><br>
                <label>Phone: <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" required></label><br>
                <label>address: <input type="text" placeholder="Address" id="address"></label><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Can this solution be improved by avoiding inline JS?

*Note: IIFE -Immediately-Invoked Function Expression*

Comment: This is incomplete. `verify` isn't defined. And you're not doing what the assignment is telling you to do - you're letting the browser do the input validation.

Comment: I agree with Mat, your code doesn't really solve the problem. Adding to that that your original question was `Can this solution be improved using IIFE?`, it doesn't look like you want your code reviewed, but want us to do your work. I'm voting to close for now.

Comment: Since the question already has an answer, you can't change the code. However, we could reopen the question if you modify the Problem Statement to be consistent with the code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Semantics

Put the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` before anything else that is being parsed. Some sources say it must be in the first 512 characters, some sources say it must be in the first 1024 characters. To be safe, it is wise to just put it at the start. ([source](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en#question))

You are using inline styling. I recommend to do this via CSS.

#### Events

Whenever an event is fired, the `this` keyword is set to the current element. Your use of `id` in the function definition in the `onblur` property is thus not required. If you insist on using a closure there, you could do this instead:

```
(function( element ) {
   //blah
 })( this );
```

You can avoid using inline javascript by binding an event to an element after the DOM has loaded. See [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) for more details on how to figure out when the DOM has loaded.

#### Input validation

Your solution does not actually do input validation. This can be easily demonstrated by changing the types of your input fields to "text" and trying to submit the form. Input validation should happen on the submit event ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit)) for a form. You could still use your blur event(s) to make this process easier.

Comment: But I can't assign IIFE to `document.getElementById('email').onblur`, right?

Comment: The problem statement is vague. IIFE is literally only a term to describe the construction `(function(..){})(..)`. An IIFE can just return a function for example, even though that seems kinda silly to me. It is unclear to me how they want you to use an IIFE. Hell, as far as I know they even could want you to use an IIFE in script tags outside your form in which you bind functions to specific events.

Comment: Yes you are right, IIFE can return a function. I am making the changes now by removing inline JS. [here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/acadgild/assignments/session9/assignment3/file.html) is my modified code